# After login via facebook button I can see the transition between the two activities - Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a facebook button which after it is pressed the "AfterLogin" activity starts.

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if(profile != null ){
            Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AfterLogin.class);
            upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(upanel);
            /**
             * Close Login Screen
             **/
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
};
```

In the `AfterLogin` activity I have a button which when pressed takes you back to the

```
logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(login);
                    finish();});
```

My problem is that I can see the layout of the login button from the `MainActivity` changing from `logIn` to `logOut` before the `AfterLogin` activity starting point. Also when I'm in the `AfterLogin` activity and I press the button I can see the transition from login to logout on the button, before the `MainActiviy` appears. How can I make the transition faster ? So far I have only activities in my app, but I could change some of the to fragments. Should I use fragments wherever I can ?

Is it possible to deactivate the changing of text inside the facebook login button ? (like Instagram)

Answer (score 0):

I think for the sake of transition speed between Activities you should not call finish() on any of them and let Android manage the backstack. Also you should not change the login button state immediately after clicking it but you may for example use a BroadcastReceiver class to change it from AfterLogin Activity in its onCreate() method. No you should not use fragments wherever possible, I recommend reading this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html